# How to Sent data via BLE from Android APP to BLE Reciever?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I wish to use APP as server for `BLE`, I need to sent Data on click of app  button, the app has multiple `Activities`, on click it will show next `Activity` so on, so each `Activity` will sent different data via `BLE`.

Comment: You need to write UUID characteristics values for communicate with BLE devices.https://medium.com/@avigezerit/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-22bc7310387a

Comment: i have bled112-v1 BLE Bluetooth 802.15.1 Modules BLE USB Dongle 4.0 single mode with me now,i will use it as client , i intent to sent data on click of button in app , via BLE do help me with some reference on this one